# Make the list of the hidden elements visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two lists and initially they should be hidden. When I click on the (+) button next to one them6 the list should open smoothly; if I click on the button (which at this moment should look like (-)) again, the list should be closed.

If I click on the button of the second list while the first list is opened, the first list should smoothly be hidden and the second should be shown; the same happens with the reverse situation.

I have quite a stange issue: for some reason, when the lists are closed, the (+) button is visible only next to the second list, and it appears next to the first list only if I open the second one.

What am I doing wrong? To be honest, I don't even know if it's a problem of my JS code or something's wrong with css/html.

```js
var buttonSections = document.querySelector(".open-sections");
var buttonContacts = document.querySelector(".open-contacts");
var sectionsList = document.querySelector(".sections__list");
var contactsList = document.querySelector(".contacts__list");
var TABLET_WIDTH = 767;
buttonSections.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (sectionsList.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    sectionsList.classList.remove("hidden");
    sectionsList.classList.add("open");
    buttonSections.style.value = "-";
    buttonSections.style.width = "16px";
    buttonSections.style.height = "1px";
  } else if (sectionsList.classList.contains("open")) {
    sectionsList.classList.remove("open");
    sectionsList.classList.add("hidden");
    buttonSections.style.value = "+";
    buttonSections.style.width = "16px";
    buttonSections.style.height = "16px";
  }
  if (contactsList.classList.contains("open")) {
    buttonSections.style.value = "-";
    contactsList.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});

buttonContacts.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (contactsList.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    contactsList.classList.remove("hidden");
    contactsList.classList.add("open");
    buttonSections.style.value = "-";
    buttonContacts.style.width = "16px";
    buttonContacts.style.height = "1px";
  } else if (contactsList.classList.contains("open")) {
    contactsList.classList.remove("open");
    contactsList.classList.add("hidden");
    buttonSections.style.value = "+";
    buttonContacts.style.width = "16px";
    buttonContacts.style.height = "16px";
  }
  if (sectionsList.classList.contains("open")) {
    buttonSections.style.value = "-";
    sectionsList.classList.add("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.page-footer__extra {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 77px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

.page-footer__sections {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 225px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.page-footer__sections::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: -300px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1067px;
  background-color: #626962;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.open-sections {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: -63px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("../img/icons/button-open-sections.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sections__list {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.page-footer__sections--heading {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1B2D37;
}

.sections__list--item-link {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #1B2D37;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sections__list--item:nth-child(2n-1) {
  min-width: 165px;
}

.item__delivery,
.item__contacts {
  min-width: 114px;
}

.page-footer__contacts {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.open-contacts {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("../img/icons/button-open-contacts.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.page-footer__contacts--heading {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #1B2D37;
}

.contacts__list {
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contacts__list--link {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #1B2D37;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-footer__extra">
  <!-- Sections of the website block -->
  <div class="page-footer__sections">
    <h3 class="title page-footer__sections--heading">Разделы сайта</h3>
    <input class="open-sections" type="button" value="+" />
    <ul class="sections__list list-reset">
      <li class="sections__list--item item__about-company">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">O компании</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__details">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Комплектующие</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__products">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Продукты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__delivery">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Доставка</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__production">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link link-production" href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__contacts">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sections__list--item item__repairs">
        <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Contacts block -->
  <div class="page-footer__contacts">
    <input class="open-contacts" type="button" value="+" />
    <h3 class="title page-footer__contacts--heading">Наш офис</h3>
    <ul class="contacts__list list-reset">
      <li class="contacts__list--item">
        <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">г. Мытищи, Олимпийский проспект, д.10</a>
      </li>
      <li class="contacts__list--item">
        <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (495) 589-40-50</a>
      </li>
      <li class="contacts__list--item">
        <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (925) 003-87-67</a>
      </li>
      <li class="contacts__list--item">
        <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (926) 926-080-79</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code snippet does not do anything, there's no `-` or `+` to click

Comment: Could have also done something similar to this. https://codepen.io/ArundeepChohan/pen/gOYJPgw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are trying to create an accordion, you need to hide all `ul` at the very beginning.

Then you can tell javacsript to show only the `ul` sibling of the button that just got hit.

Here is an illustration, note that there are many ways to do this, and i am using [the Spread syntax commonly called The Spread Operator: ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)  but with the code bellow you can add as much as `page-footer__` as you want following this same HTML structure.

```js
var button = [...document.querySelectorAll("[class^='open-']")]; 

button.forEach(function(element){
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
var parent = this.parentElement.className;
 document.querySelector(".page-footer__extra > [class^='page-footer__']:not(."+parent+") >ul").classList.add("hidden");
  this.parentNode.querySelector("ul").classList.remove("hidden")

},false);
})
```

```css
.page-footer__extra {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-top: 77px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

.page-footer__sections {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 225px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

.page-footer__sections::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: -300px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1067px;
  background-color: #626962;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

.open-sections {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: -63px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("../img/icons/button-open-sections.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sections__list {
  margin-top: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.page-footer__sections--heading {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1B2D37;
}

.sections__list--item-link {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #1B2D37;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.sections__list--item:nth-child(2n-1) {
  min-width: 165px;
}

.item__delivery,
.item__contacts {
  min-width: 114px;
}

.page-footer__contacts {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 33px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 26px;
}

.open-contacts {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: -15px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("../img/icons/button-open-contacts.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.page-footer__contacts--heading {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #1B2D37;
}

.contacts__list {
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contacts__list--link {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #1B2D37;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.hidden{
  display:none
}
```

```html
You are trying to create an accordion
   

<div class="page-footer__extra">
    <!-- Sections of the website block -->
    <div class="page-footer__sections">
        <h3 class="title page-footer__sections--heading">Разделы сайта</h3>
        <button class="open-sections">open-sections</button>
        <ul class="sections__list list-reset hidden">
            <li class="sections__list--item item__about-company">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">O компании</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__details">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Комплектующие</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__products">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Продукты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__delivery">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Доставка</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__production">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link link-production" href="#">Производство печатных плат</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__contacts">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Контакты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sections__list--item item__repairs">
                <a class="link sections__list--item-link" href="#">Монтаж печатных плат</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Contacts block -->
    <div class="page-footer__contacts">
        <h3 class="title page-footer__contacts--heading">Наш офис</h3>
        <button class="open-contacts">open-contacts</button>
        <ul class="contacts__list list-reset hidden">
            <li class="contacts__list--item">
                <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">г. Мытищи, Олимпийский проспект, д.10</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contacts__list--item">
                <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (495) 589-40-50</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contacts__list--item">
                <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (925) 003-87-67</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contacts__list--item">
                <a class="link contacts__list--link" href="#">+7 (926) 926-080-79</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really game us a reproducable example. Your `<button>` tag doesn't work because you didn't gave us the code for custom elements, so I had to change it to `<input type="button" value="+"/>`.

Anyway, what makes your code faulty is that you never remove `open` from your else if statement.

I would suggest that you only use one class: either the lists are "open", or they are "hidden".  You don't need to have both. It only creates confusion, which is what happened here. I would suggest that you go with "hidden" as only class.